What is the reason that the bridge pickup on a Strat is often wound for greater output?
I am a relative newcomer to building electric guitars.
What is the reason that the bridge pickup on a Strat is often wound for greater output? Why does average output vary, for example: Neck 6.7K, Middle 7.1K, and Bridge 7.6K?

The numbers are resistances in Ohms, I guess?

Could well be something to do with the fact that strings have smaller vibration towards the bridge, thus needing extra output from the pups, the closer they are to that bridge?

@user1079505 yes the numbers are resistances in Ohms. The resistance of the coil winding doesn't measure the output, but when comparing pickups of the same overall construction then higher resistance = more coil winds = higher output (and usually a slightly darker tone) so it's widely used as a proxy measure.

The string is held in place by the bridge, so the closer a pickup is to the bridge, the less string movement there is above it, mainly for the lowest frequency partials.
If you used 3 identical pickups, then the bridge pickup would pick up less low end than the middle pickup, and the middle pickup would pick up less low end than the neck pickup.  Thus the bridge pickup would sound quietest overall, followed by the middle and then neck pickup.
By having a slightly hotter middle and bridge pickup, you compensate for the volume loss of the missing low end, and you end up with three pickups that are roughly the same volume but with different tonal balances.

I feel like another reason is common use and sound of bridge pickups. High gain rock and metal sounds far more often use the bridge pickup, so having higher output on that pickup helps get the desired sound in many situations.
